# Proxy directory to another url with httpd proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Currently Im trying to forward a directory in my domain to domain with port.  The reason I'm trying to do this is because my server is apache but I need to access just one node file.

I'm posting some data coming from another domain.

I need this:

```
http://example.com/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/
```

To forward to

```
http://example.com:3000/
```

in httpd.conf I've added this:

```
# mod_proxy setup.
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /preview/productpreview/node-webshot http://example.com:3000/
<Location "/preview/productpreview/node-webshot">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>
```

My expected result was that when I hit the url specified above that it would forward to the domain as indicated above.

I'm not sure what I'm doing with this so I don't even know where to begin.
I took the above code from my server provider.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a slash to both value

`ProxyPass /preview/productpreview/node-webshot/ http://example.com:3000/`

[Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

`ProxyPass "/mirror/foo/" "http://backend.example.com/"
If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.`